# std::is_assignable and const pointer object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I have a small problem when trying to deduce things with `std::is_assignable`

## My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class Object{};

enum my_conv {
  string, const_object, object
};

template<typename T, typename V = void>
struct deducer;

template<typename T>
struct deducer<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value >::type > {
  static const my_conv value = my_conv::string;
}; // (1) test for string                                                                                              

template<typename T>
struct deducer<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_assignable<Object*&, T>::value >::type > {
  static const my_conv value = my_conv::object;
}; // (2) test for Object derived                                                                                      

template<typename T>
struct deducer<const T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_assignable<Object*&, T>::value >::type > {
  static const my_conv value = my_conv::const_object;
}; // (3) should test for const Object derived                                                                         

class Test : public Object {
public:
  Test() = default;
};

int main() {
  std::string   str;
  Test*         t = new Test;
  const Test*   tconst = static_cast<const Test*>(t);

  deducer<decltype(t)>::value;// deduce as (1)                                                                         
  deducer<decltype(str)>::value;//deduce as (2)                                                                        
  deducer<decltype(tconst)>::value;//fail to deduce as (3)... why?                                                     
}
```

And I really don't understand why the compiler fail to instantiate the third deducer....

## Edit:

When testing I have seen that writing that:

```
struct deducer<const T*, typename std::enable_if< std::is_assignable<Object*&, T*>::value >::type >
```

make it work, but I think I still need some explanation... because I still don't understand what is wrong in the first time....

Comment: I guess you mean "fail to deduce as (3)"? Obviously it won't deduce as (1) since it isn't constructible from a string.

Comment: `const Test*` is neither convertible into `std::string` nor `Object*&`

Comment: sorry i meant fail to deduce as (3)

Comment: It fails, since `const T` can't be matched against `const T*`, since `const T` is equivalent to `T const`, and for a pointer to const it would be `const T* const`, and also, `const T*` can't obviously be assigned to a non-const pointer to base class

Comment: @Jarod42 bu the third one should success as the T is of type Object* if the given type is const Object*

Comment: @PiotrS. thanks!! I didn't think this in that way! could you post your answer in order to close this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it won't match (1) because `const Test *` is not constructible from `std::string`.

It won't match (2) because a pointer-to-const is not assignable to a non-const pointer.

It won't match (3) because that's for constant types, not pointers to constant types.

Remember that, if `T` is a pointer type like `Test*`, then `const T` is a constant pointer `Test * const`, not a pointer-to-constant `Test const *`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `tconst` is a non-`const` pointer to a `const Test`. As such, it is matched against class template specialization no `(2)`:

```
template<typename T>
struct deducer<T, // [...]
```

with `T = const Test*`, rather than `(3)`, which matches `T const` types (like `Test* const`, which is different than `const Test*`).

However, it would still fail to compile, falling back to your incomplete primary class template, since the assignability test is unsuccessful when an attempt is made to assign a `const Test*` (deduced `T`) to a pointer of `Object*&` type (missing a `const` qualifier).